# Infinite scroll js: locally hosted loading gif

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

Working on a project using the [infinite scroll javascript](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) library. I'm trying to use a gif I have downloaded as the loading image when the infinite scroll library is making its ajax call to the server.

However no matter how I do the image routing it will not grab the loading gif I have downloaded. Very frustrating since there error will look like this "GET http://localhost:3000/app/assets/images/myblend-loading.gif 404 (Not Found)" which is exactly where I have the image hosted (though I don't have a route to it).

Does anyone know how to use a locally hosted gif with this library?

```
$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector: 'nav.pagination', // selector for the paged navigation
  nextSelector: 'nav.pagination a[rel=next]', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector: '#discover_content div.discover-article', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  bufferPx: Math.round($(window).height() * 1.5),
  pixelsFromNavToBottom: Math.round($(window).height() * 1.5),
  loading: {
    finishedMsg: 'No more products to load.',
    msgText: "",
    img: "/app/assets/images/myblend-loading.gif" #this should be where the image is hosted
  }
}
```

Comment: If you click that link does it load the gif?

Comment: @MannfromReno No it just goes to the 'Network' tab of my inspect console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/assets/myblend-loading.gif
```

You could also put it in the public folder and just do

```
/myblend-loading.gif
```